# How to use --experimental option in bal build

Tags: ballerina, ballerina-swan-lake

I am currently working on upgrading a Ballerina program from 2201.1.0 to 2201.4.1. This program was containerized and the build command in the Dockerfile was `RUN bal build --experimental` . When I use the same build command with 2201.4.1, I get an error saying `ballerina: unknown option: '--experimental'`.

What does this option do and what should I use in 2201.4.1 ?
I checked  `bal dist use 2201.1.0 && bal build --help`  also but couldn't find information about this option there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `--experimental` flag  was introduced when some language features were in the experimental stage in Swan Lake. It is not required now since the features are stable. You can simply remove the flag and execute the command.